# creating a person taking a random walk in python

Tags: bayesian

my teacher ask me to create a person taking a random walk across a coordinate starting with (0,0)
please help me generates a random (x,y) pair that make up a point on coordinate system.

start with:
 pt1: (0,0)
 pt2: (7.17)
 pt3: (12,3)
 pt4: (8,2)
 pt5: (7,6)

then calculate distance between pt1 and pt2, pt2 and pt3, pt3 and pt4, pt4 and pt5

please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything, how has what you tried failed? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Think how you would calculate the distance between two points without Python. All you need to implement that equation in a method using Python's [math functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions).